# Matlab extend plot over all axis range

Tags: matlab, plot, line, algebra

I'm trying to use Matlab for some data plotting.  In particular I need to plot a series of lines, some times given two points belonging to it, some times given the orthogonal vector.

I've used the following to obtain the plot of the line:

1. Line given two points `A = [A(1), A(2)] B = [B(1), B(2)]`:

   ```
   plot([A(1),B(1)],[A(2),B(2)])
   ```
2. Line given the vector `W = [W(1), W(2)]'`:

   ```
   if( W(1) == 0 )
       plot( [W(1), rand(1)] ,[W(2), W(2)]) 
   else
       plot([W(1), W(1) + (W(2)^2 / W(1))],[W(2),0]) 
   end
   ```

   where I'm calculating the intersection between the x-axis and the line using the second theorem of Euclid on the triangle rectangle formed by the vector W and the line.

[image]

My problem as you can see from the picture above is that the line will only be plotted between the two points and not on all the range of my axis.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I have a line going across the whole axis range?
2. Is there a more easy and direct way (maybe a function?) to plot the line perpendicular to a vector?  (An easier and more clean way to solve point 2 above.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have two bounds on the line, you can always use `interp1` or another interpolation functions to get values outside/inside of your bounds

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - Thks for the comment, but I don't understand a thing: I don't need to interpolate them, cause I have the equation of the line so I can know its value on all the axis, I just need to plot it...any idea for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the bounds of your axis for displaying the plot? If so, you can specify the range of the plot with the `axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])` function.

So, from your question, if you know the slope `m` and intercept `b`, you can make sure your function plots the line across the whole window by specifying:

```
plot([xmin, xmax], [m*xmin + b, m*xmax + b]);
axis([xmin, xmax, min(m*xmin+b, m*xmax+b), max(m*xmin+b, m*xmax+b)]);
```

where `xmin` and `xmax` are values you specify as the range of your x-axis. This will make your line go from the corner of your plot to the other corner. If you want a buffer in the y-direction, then add one like so:

```
buffer = 5; % for example, you set this to something that looks good.
axis([xmin, xmax, min(m*xmin+b, m*xmax+b)-buffer, max(m*xmin+b, m*xmax+b)+buffer]);
```

Comment: thks, that is what I was thinking about as well!what do you mean by buffer?

Comment: So by buffer, I mean if you don't want the line going from the corners of your plot and instead want a white space buffer above and below the line.

Comment: As for the second part, I'm not sure what you mean by a more direct way. If your linear algebra works, why do you need to replace it with a function?